# What does NS_IMETHODIMP means in a XPCOM?

Tags: xpcom, xulrunner

I'm having trouble to find the meaning of his NS_IMETHODIMP in a XPCOM, and I would like to understand this function's signature:

```
NS_IMETHODIMP myConfig::GetProperty(const char *name, char **_retval NS_OUTPARAM)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your platform, but in general it's just a `#define` for `nsresult`.  On Windows, it's a bit different, and it's a `#define` for `nsresult __stdcall`.

Comment: I'm on linux, nsresult means that the method has a non void return?

Comment: @Tom Brito - correct, you could simple see that as `nsresult myConfig::GetProperty(const char *name, char **_retval NS_OUTPARAM)`

Comment: @Tom Brito An interface method usually returns NS_OK for success and one of the many NS_ERROR codes for failure.